# SCL python on oel6 linux inside a docker container

Tags: docker, scl, oel

I have a dockerfile building oel6 linux that uses the SCL python27.

For the docker build, using the `SHELL` command works to execute the commands correctly (i.e. if i were to insert a `RUN python --version` i get 2.7).

Creating a `/root/.bashrc` that sets `source scl_source enable python27` works great for any interactive sessions with the container (`python --version` 2.7)

However, any commands executed non-interactively  (i.e. `docker run oel6 pyhton --version`) is always 2.6 no matter what i try.

Take what i've tried with a grain of salt as i may have tried it incorrectly but i've tried setting the entrypoint as the command, i've tried executing a script that contains the commands as an entrypoint, i've tried putting it in /etc/profile.d/.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I  suggest that you share your Dockerfile / entrypoint script to get better help

Comment: Why on earth are you using oel6 and trying to add SCL python27 on it in a docker container?!!

Comment: I don't make the rules, mike, i just follow them.

Comment: Yes, but when they're apparently ridiculous, you should at least question what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found this site: https://austindewey.com/2019/03/26/enabling-software-collections-binaries-on-a-docker-image/

I had my entrypoint script wrong. What works is:

```
#!/bin/bash
source scl_source enable python27
exec "$@"
```